# view the angular array in php page ..

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, json

i have tried to view the PHP errors in array to angular ..
this is the angular code

```
                    $http.post('includes/functions/functions.php',$.param(values))
                .success(function(d){
                    $scope.error = (angular.isObject(d))?{d}:'';
                    console.log(d);
                })
```

php Code

```
            if(empty($name)) 
                $error[] = 'name empty';
            if(empty($email)) 
                $error[] = 'email empty';
            if(empty($password)) 
                $error[] = 'password empty ';
            if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                $error[] =  " email not correct";

            $res = $connect->prepare("SELECT email,num_phone FROM pta_users WHERE email = :email ");
            $res->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $res->execute();
            $member = $res->FetchAll();

            if($res->rowCount() > 0){

                    $error[] = 'this email has register before  ';
            }
                echo json_encode($error);
```

the json_encode() return value like that

```
["email empty", " email not correct", "name empty"]
```

i try this one but not work ,

```
     <div class="text-center" ng-repeat="error in err">
  <span>{{err}}</span>
</div>
```

How can I view errors?
i use angularjs v1.5.11

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the data property of it

```
 $scope.error = d.data;
```

Comment: what do you when you put console.log(d);

Comment: just to check the result .

Comment: i mean what do you see

Comment: This is the problem previously when fetching a value comes key and value 
{name: 'ali',age:18}
But now there is no key to value
just values {'ali',18}
how i can loop this values in div by angular ?

Comment: its an object. so you cannot loop

Comment: is there any solution to loop the array in div

Comment: am saying your response is not an array